# I want to align image view based on number of images multiple rows and two columns using for loop in ios

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiimageview

add uiimageview two columns and multiple rows . for example no_ofimages 3 then 1st row with two images got filled and second row with one image need to be filled .......

```
CGFloat marginX = self.view.frame.size.width *0.45;
CGFloat marginY = self.view.frame.size.height * 0.12;
CGRect ImageFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.view.frame.size.height *0.2, self.view.frame.size.width *0.4, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.1);


if(isiPad)
{


    for(int i=1;i<no_ofitems;i++)
    {
       //int rows = i/2;

        int columns = i %2;

      //  for(int j=-1;j<rows;j++)
      //  {
      //
            for (int k=0;k<=columns;k++)
            {

                UIImageView *InApp_imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:ImageFrame];

                [InApp_imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonbg.png"]];

                [self.view addSubview:InApp_imageview];
                ImageFrame.origin.x += marginX;




            }

            ImageFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.05;
            ImageFrame.origin.y += marginY;
       // }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Choice-1**

> customize yourself

create progrmatically

```
// initially set the x and y frames as zero 
x=0;
y=0;

 // crete the scrollview for the purpose of scroll actually we dont know how much data will comes.
 UIScrollView  *scroller=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
          scroller.frame=CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 250.0, 250.0); // customize the frame

scroller.delegate=self;

[self.view addSubview:scroller];
// set the  ContentSize based on array count * visible of Items per row * some heights
[scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(300,(([no_ofitems count]+2-1)/2)*20))];


for (int i=1; i<[no_ofitems count]+1; i++)
{   
    // using modulo for split the items when its reach to limit
    if (x%2==0)
    {
        x=0;
        y++; // increase the y frame based on split
    }

    UIImageView * InApp_imageview =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x*60, y*60, 50, 50)];  // here its automatically set the frame for each height

      [InApp_imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonbg.png"]];
     InApp_imageview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

            InApp_imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            InApp_imageview.tag=i-1;
    [scroller addSubview: InApp_imageview];
    InApp_imageview =nil;
    x++; // increase the each x frame based on array count
}
```

**Choice-2**

use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) it is subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik I didn't get it

Comment: @divyaswaminathan - in which part u not understand

Comment: if you need the support ask me I surely explain my code

Comment: @divyaswaminathan -- sure

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik  now i understand.